# Hibernate Lock Object for 4 eye check

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, locking

I have a database application with objects, that shall only be modified using a 4/6 eyes check.

For example:
I have a "Person" in a database, and the attribute "person_name" (or any other attribute of that object) can only be changed once the change has been reviewed by someone else. 
For that, a new object "Person_modification" is created in the database, that has an attribute "approvement_status" with possible values "approved", "rejected" etc..

From the moment the new object "Person_modification" has been created, until its either in status "approved" or "rejected", the underlying "Person" object should be locked, i.e. it must not be modifiable by any other user/transaction.
I.e. between the initial change and the approval of the change could lie days or weeks/ months. During that time, the object should not be modifiable.

Is there a functionality in Hibernate, that lets me put such a lock on an object that lasts way beyond a "transaction" in a hibernate sense until its manually released?

Or would the way to go here to create an additional attribute on the "Person" object that inidicates if its currently being modified by a "Person_modification" object?

Comment: go with additional attributes instead of hibernate based as they are transactional only .

Answer (score 0):

go with additional attributes instead of hibernate based as they are transactional only .
you can create triggers which can monitor updates and allow them only when certain conditions are true